# Find the limit of a function, given its graph

Tags: calculus, limits

> For the function f whose graph is shown (I uploaded the graph), state the value of the limit. If the limit does not exist, write DNE.

(My answers are below)

[image: Graph]

a. $\lim_{x\to -3} f(x) = 4$

b. $\lim_{x\to 5-} f(x) =$ DNE

c. $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = -1$

d. $\lim_{x\to1} f(x) = 0$ (not sure about this one)

Do you think my answers are correct?

Comment: Ahh never mind, I think it's correct because it approach 0 from both sides.

Comment: @DavidH I don't see a reason to be unsure. Holiday: yes, all answers are correct. Note that I reformatted the formulas:   see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: So all my answers are correct?

Comment: @Thursday My mistake. I misread the question as asking for the limit as $x\to 0$. I blame the lack of Tex pre-edit :)

Answer (score 2):

All answers are correct, assuming that the vertical axis has the same scale as horizontal, i.e., the grid lines are $1$ unit apart. 
It would be better if whoever made the graph  placed some numbers on the vertical axis too.